# sed or awk to print lines between words

Tags: sed

how to print all lines between 
"section B ("
To the next "section" word that begin in line?

section A (

.
.

)

section B (

.
.

)

section C (

.
.

)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to print everything from "section B" to "section C" *including* those lines,

```
sed -ne '/^section B/,/^section/p'
```

If you don't want to print the two "section" lines,

```
sed -e '1,/^section B/d' -e '/^section/,$d'
```

If you want to include "section B" and the closing parenthesis (but not "section C"),

```
sed -ne '/^section B/,/^)/p'
```

And there are a few other possible variants.

Answer (score 6):

```
sed -n '
  /^section B/!n;
  /^section B/d;
  /^)/q;
  p
' yourfile
```

Explanation of the above sed script, in steps:

1. While the line does not `!` start with `section B` move to the next line.
2. After the we reached the desired line remove the `section B` text line.
3. In case the line starts with `)` we quit.
4. Else we print the currently processed line.

Comment: Somehow `/^section B/!n;` let me print what is before that line.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n '/section B/,/)/p' file
```

or awk

```
awk '/section B/,/)/{print}' file

awk -vRS=")" '/section B/{print $0RT}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

In general if you want to "maintain state" between lines in a file - like you do here - then sed won't do the job.  Awk is probably the next-simplest tool you can use in this instance.

The following awk script would do what you want:

```
/^section\ B\ \(/   {InSection=1; next;}
/^\)/       {InSection=0; next;}
//          {if (InSection) print $0;}
```