# how to print text between two specific words using awk, sed?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

how to print text between two specific words using awk, sed ?

```
$ ofed_info | awk '/MLNX_OFED_LINUX/{print}'
MLNX_OFED_LINUX-4.1-1.0.2.0 (OFED-4.1-1.0.2):
$
```

Output required:-

```
4.1-1.0.2.0
```

Comment: asokan, always do add your efforts in your post too in code tags.

Comment: I did added the effort on code tag which is using awk !

Comment: [How to use sed/grep to extract text between two words?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13242469/), [sed or awk to print lines between words](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3551731), [Extract text between two strings repeatedly using sed or awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13386080/), [Sed to extract text between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16643288/), [Extract data between two strings using either AWK or SED](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16814473), [How to select lines between two marker patterns which may occur multiple times with awk/sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17988756), etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you here.(considering that your input to `awk` will be same as shown sample only)

```
your_command | awk '{sub(/[^-]*/,"");sub(/ .*/,"");sub(/-/,"");print}'
```

***Solution 2nd:*** With `sed` solution now.

```
your_command | sed 's/\([^-]*\)-\([^ ]*\).*/\2/'
```

***Solution 3rd:*** Using `awk`'s `match` utility:

```
your_command | awk 'match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

Comment: didn't work, got this output "4.11.0.2.0 "

Comment: @asokan, check now and let me know?

Comment: Not my downvote, but I'll repeat my advice to abstain from answering obvious duplicates.  E.g. the [Stack Overflow `bash` tag wiki](/tags/bash/info) has a good selection of canonical answers to very common questions.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559897/replace-line-with-space-and-backslash-with-a-string-containing-spaces/50559951#comment88151230_50559897

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `sed`:

```
echo 'MLNX_OFED_LINUX-4.1-1.0.2.0 (OFED-4.1-1.0.2):' |
sed -E 's/^[^-]*-| .*//g'
```

```
4.1-1.0.2.0
```

This `sed` command removes text till first hyphen from start or text starting with space towards end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ofed_info | sed -n 's/^MLNX_OFED_LINUX-\([^ ]\+\).*/\1/p'
```

The `sed` command only selects lines starting with the keyword and prints the version attached to it.