# How can I use sed/awk/grep to print lines between the two identical words in a separate file?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I would like to print all the lines between the two patterns, each part in a separate file.

The pattern:

```
ATOM  10185  O   WAT   622      86.629 114.783 125.073  1.00  0.00.  
ATOM  10186  H1  WAT   622      87.265 114.479 125.721  1.00  0.00.  
ATOM  10187  H2  WAT   622      86.215 115.543 125.482  1.00  0.00.  
TER  
ATOM  10188  O   WAT   623      84.441 115.565 126.663  1.00  0.00.  
ATOM  10189  H1  WAT   623      85.076 115.261 127.311  1.00  0.00.  
ATOM  10190  H2  WAT   623      84.027 116.325 127.071  1.00  0.00.  
TER  
ATOM  10191  O   WAT   624      85.591 117.441 124.690  1.00  0.00.    
ATOM  10192  H1  WAT   624      86.226 117.137 125.338  1.00  0.00.   
ATOM  10193  H2  WAT   624      85.176 118.201 125.098  1.00  0.00.   
TER
```

What I want to have in the new files is:

file1:

```
ATOM  10185  O   WAT   622      86.629 114.783 125.073  1.00  0.00.  
ATOM  10186  H1  WAT   622      87.265 114.479 125.721  1.00  0.00.  
ATOM  10187  H2  WAT   622      86.215 115.543 125.482  1.00  0.00.  
TER
```

file2:

```
ATOM  10188  O   WAT   623      84.441 115.565 126.663  1.00  0.00.  
ATOM  10189  H1  WAT   623      85.076 115.261 127.311  1.00  0.00.  
ATOM  10190  H2  WAT   623      84.027 116.325 127.071  1.00  0.00.  
TER
```

etc.

I tried all I found on the site and the internet, but I do not get what I need in the end. It is mostly how to grep between the two patterns like patern1xxxxxpatern2 and than print them in a file. ([sed or awk to print lines between words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548864/sed-or-awk-to-print-lines-between-words), https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264962/print-lines-of-a-file-between-two-matching-patterns/264977 and similar)

I tried this, but I get the error `awk: illegal statement at source line 1`:

```
awk '/TER/{n+=1}{print > "file_"n".txt"}'
```

Thanks

Comment: You're not printing blocks of text between two words, you're printing blocks of text that end with a word.

Answer (score 1):

man(1) awk on BSD-like systems gives this answer:

```
/start/, /stop/
              Print all lines between start/stop pairs.


% cat 1.txt
l-2
l-1
TER1
l1
l2
l3
l4
l5
TER2
l6
l7
```

Test:

```
% awk '/TER1/, /TER2/' 1.txt 
TER1
l1
l2
l3
l4
l5
TER2
```

Comment: Can you write the entire expression? I am not using awk that often, I must say. I used something similar with sed -n '/TER/,/TER/p' file1 > file2, but I want each part in a separate output file. I have very large files.

Comment: So, since after each segment I have "TER" and not "TER1", "TER2" this does not work. If I use TER in both pattern1 and pattern2 I get only word TER printed in the output file.

Comment: Never use range expressions (`/start/,/stop/`) as they make trivial tasks very slightly briefer to write than other approaches but then need a complete rewrite and/or duplicate conditions for anything even the tiniest bit more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

wrt:

> I tried this, but I get the error "awk: illegal statement at
>   source line 1":
>
> awk '/TER/{n+=1}{print > "file_"n".txt"}'

that's probably due to the unparenthesized expression on the right side of the output redirection as that's undefined behavior per POSIX. If so then changing `"file_"n".txt"` to `("file_"n".txt")` would get you past that and on to your next problem. Here's how to really do what you want with any awk though:

```
awk '
BEGIN { out = "file" (++c) }
{ print > out }
$0=="TER" {
    close(out)
    out = "file" (++c)
}
' file
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, I tried your code (I must say I do not fully understand what all the commands mean, like ++c), but what I get is one output file with all segments. How can I have each segment between the two TERs in separate files? Maybe I am doing something wrong, however. I am not really proficient in awk.

Comment: Again - per the example you provided in your question you are not trying to get each segment between 2 TERs, you are trying to get each segment that ends with a TER. If the script I posted doesn't do exactly what you wanted then your real data doesn't look like the example you provided. You MAY had DOS line endings so try running `dos2unix` or similar on your file. Or less robustly you can change `$0=="TER"` to `/TER/`.

Comment: I updated the way my data looks in the question. It can be that I am not expressing my self correctly, indeed.

Comment: The solution I posted will work for any data that ends with TER alone on a line including your original data and your new data.. wrt what `++c` means - In your own code you wrote `n+=1`, you could instead write `++n` or `n++` in that context. It's just incrementing the variable `n` or in my case `c` (for "count"). I formatted your input, output, and code for you so you have that example to follow for your next question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for more formatting info.

Comment: If the script I posted doesn't do exactly what you want, please do let me know as it is exactly the solution you need given the data you posted so if it doesn't work for you then either you copy/pasted my script wrong or your real data doesn't look like your sample data (may just be trailing `\`r`s as I mentioned previously).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU csplit):

```
csplit -sb '%d' -zf file inputFile '/^TER/+1' '{*}'
```

This creates file `file0` through to `filen` each containing the pattern `TER` as the last line of each file.